# SQL Conditional Where statement?

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, where-clause, statements

I work at a hospital group where we have multiple site servers, organized into about 6 regions.  I'm writing a sql query in SCCM and want to resolve region with site, and it's proving to be a challenge...I want to do a selective where statement based on which region I'm querying, but I'm not sure if it can be done.  I know the following code is broken...specifically the case statement near the where lines.  Is there something possible like that to use in this case?

```
DECLARE @test AS varchar(4) = 'WBR';
SELECT 
    DISTINCT MEMB.Netbios_Name0 AS [Computer Name],
    v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Manufacturer0 AS [Computer Manufacturer], 
    v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Model0 AS [Computer Model], 
    v_GS_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE_CATEGORIZED.ProductName0 AS [Product Name], 
    v_GS_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE_CATEGORIZED.Publisher0 AS [Publisher],
    v_GS_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE_CATEGORIZED.SoftwareID AS [SoftwareID], 
    MEMB.SiteCode AS [Site],
    CASE MEMB.SiteCode
        When 'AB1' Then 'EBR' 
        When 'AM1' Then 'SSR'
        When 'CMB' Then 'PCR'
        When 'CO1' Then 'WBR'
        When 'CP1' Then 'WBR'
        When 'CUC' Then 'PCR'
        When 'DM1' Then 'EBR'
        When 'EM1' Then 'EBR'
        When 'LS1' Then 'WBR'
        When 'MM1' Then 'CVR'
        When 'MM2' Then 'CVR'
        When 'MP1' Then 'PCR'
        When 'MP2' Then 'PCR'
        When 'NM1' Then 'SSR'
        When 'NV1' Then 'WBR'
        When 'PA1' Then 'PCR'
        When 'PAF' Then 'PCR'
        When 'PDU' Then 'PCR'
        When 'PLA' Then 'PCR'
        When 'PMF' Then 'PCR'
        When 'PMO' Then 'PCR'
        When 'PMP' Then 'PCR'
        When 'POR' Then 'PCR'
        When 'PPV' Then 'PCR'
        When 'PRS' Then 'PCR'
        When 'PSA' Then 'PCR'
        When 'SC1' Then 'CCS'
        When 'SF1' Then 'SSR'
        When 'SG1' Then 'SSR'
        When 'SH1' Then 'PCR'
        When 'SM1' Then 'SSR'
        When 'SR1' Then 'WBR'
        When 'SS1' Then 'CCS'
        When 'SZ1' Then 'PCR'
        When 'SZ2' Then 'PCR'
        When 'VN1' Then 'SCH'
        else 'Unknown'
    end 'Region',
    v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.UserName0 AS [Last User]

    FROM v_GS_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE_CATEGORIZED 
    INNER JOIN 
    ( 
        select 
            distinct v_R_System_Valid.ResourceID, 
            v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode,
            v_R_System_Valid.Netbios_Name0 

            from v_R_System_Valid 
            INNER JOIN v_FullCollectionMembership ON    v_FullCollectionMembership.ResourceID = v_R_System_Valid.ResourceID 

            case @test
                when 'SCAH' Then (where v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='VN1')
                when 'CCS' Then (where v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='SS1' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='SC1' )
                when 'CVR' Then (where v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='MM1' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='MM2')
                when 'EBR' Then (where v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='AB1' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='DM1' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='EM1')
                when 'PCR' Then (where v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='CMB' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='CUC' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='MP1' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='MP2' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='PA1' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='PAF' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='PDU' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='PLA' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='PMF' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='PMO' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='PMP' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='POR' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='PPV' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='PRS' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='PSA' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='SH1' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='SZ1' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='SZ2')
                when 'SSR' Then (where v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='AM1' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='NM1' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='SF1' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='SG1' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='SM1')
                when 'WBR' Then (where v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='CO1' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='CP1' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='LS1' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='NV1' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='SR1')
            end
            --SCAH
            --where v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='VN1'
            --CCS
            --where v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='SS1' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='SC1' 
            --CVR
            --where v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='MM1' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='MM2'
            --EBR
            --where v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='AB1' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='DM1' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='EM1'
            --PCR
            --where v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='CMB' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='CUC' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='MP1' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='MP2' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='PA1' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='PAF' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='PDU' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='PLA' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='PMF' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='PMO' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='PMP' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='POR' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='PPV' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='PRS' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='PSA' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='SH1' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='SZ1' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='SZ2'
            --SSR
            --where v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='AM1' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='NM1' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='SF1' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='SG1' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='SM1'
            --WBR
            --where v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='CO1' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='CP1' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='LS1' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='NV1' OR v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='SR1'
    ) MEMB on MEMB.ResourceID = v_GS_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE_CATEGORIZED.ResourceID 
    INNER JOIN v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM on v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.ResourceID = MEMB.ResourceID 

    where v_GS_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE_CATEGORIZED.SoftwareID = '76F63E67-3A8F-4675-9FB1-08A3E40CE9FE'
    --where v_GS_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE_CATEGORIZED.SoftwareID = @SoftwareID
    Order by MEMB.Netbios_Name0 ASC
```

Comment: With that size of a list, I would just put the list of values in another table and query that with a left outer join on `AltTable.Code = MEMB.SiteCode`. Then, in your select, you can do a
`COALESCE(AltTable.Value, 'Unknown')` so it'd use 'Unknown' if nothing was returned...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put a `where` statement:

```
  (case when @test = 'SCAH' and v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode='VN1' then 'true'
        when @test = 'CCS' and e v_FullCollectionMembership.SiteCode in ('SS1', 'SC1') 
        . . .
  end) = 'true'
```

I would suggest moving this down to a `where` clause instead of trying to keep it in the `on` clause.  If it stays in the `on` clause, you will need to precede it with `and` (or `or`, depending on the logic).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a "selective where" clause, you can also use dynamic sql.

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = 'select * from table '
if( @regions = '??')
  set @sql = @sql + ' where ....'
else if( @regions = '???' )
  set @sql = @sql + ' where ...'
exec(@sql)
```

Comment: Ok, it looks like this will work...and I don't have 15 rep to upvote your comment, but I'm now having issues where my permissions won't let me use exec...I'm working on that but at this point I can't quite validate my syntax.  When I get that fixed...I'll try that.